# how can convert decimals to any other bases without using arrays and strings

Tags: c

I know how can I convert decimals to any other kind of bases less than 10 but could we do this without using any arrays or strings in the C language?

1. get **n** as a input number
2. get **b** as a base that we want to convert to that.
3. print the number in **b** base

Comment: Yes, it can be done in several ways but .... SO is not a free coding service. We can help with **problems in your code** - we don't write **your code**

Comment: Have you ever done conversions between decimal, binary, hexadecimal or octal using pen and paper before? That's a very good exercise for anyone wanting to learn programming and the number bases. If you have done that, then it shouldn't be to much work to generalize it for any arbitrary base. There are also plenty of tutorials about arbitrary base conversion all over the Internet if you search a little. Once you have an algorithm on paper, it's easy to create an implementation in code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solve in this way:

1. get n as an input number.
2. get b as a base that we want to convert to that.
3. print the number in b base here is a sum.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long int n;
    int b;
    long long int sum=0;
    int i=1;
    
    scanf("%lld %d",&n,&b);
    while(n>0)
    {
    
        sum+=(n%b)*i;
        i*=10;
        n/=b;
    
    
    }
    printf("%lld",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer would be so much better if you explained the arithmetic used instead of just presenting it for copy-paste (it encourages cargo cult programming which is bad).